# pandas: dataframes row-wise comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames that I would like to compare for equality in a row-wise manner. I am interested in computing the number of rows that have the same values for non-joined attributes.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,5], 'b': [2,3,4,6], 'c':[60,20,40,30], 'd':[50,90,10,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,5], 'b': [2,3,4,6], 'c':[60,20,40,30], 'd':[50,90,40,40]})
```

I will be joining these two data frames on column `a` and `b`. There are two rows (first two) that have the same values for `c` and `d` in both the data frames.

I am currently using the following approach where I first join these two data frames, and then compute each row's values for equality.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['a','b'])
cols1 = [c for c in df.columns.tolist() if c.endswith("_x")]
cols2 = [c for c in df.columns.tolist() if c.endswith("_y")] 
num_rows_equal = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    not_equal = False
    for col1,col2 in zip(cols1,cols2):
        if row[col1] != row[col2]:
            not_equal = True
            break
    if not not_equal:  # row values are equal
        num_rows_equal += 1

num_rows_equal
```

Is there a more efficient (pythonic) way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter way of achieving that:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,5], 'b': [2,3,4,6], 'c':[60,20,40,30], 'd':[50,90,10,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,5], 'b': [2,3,4,6], 'c':[60,20,40,30], 'd':[50,90,40,40]})
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['a','b'])

comparison_cols = [c.strip('_x') for c in df.columns.tolist() if c.endswith("_x")]
num_rows_equal = (df1[comparison_cols][df1[comparison_cols] == df2[comparison_cols]].isna().sum(axis=1) == 0).sum()
```

Comment: This is giving a Series with 0 implying equal rows and 1 implying unequal rows.

Comment: The Series returned after `sum(axis=1)` is that way, but after comparing to 0 and summing, the value set in `num_rows_equal` is 2

Answer (score 1):

use [pandas merge ordered](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html), merging with 'inner'. From there, you can get your dataframe shape and by extension your number of rows.

```
 df_r = pd.merge_ordered(df1,df2,how='inner')

    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   60  50
1   2   3   20  90

no_of_rows = df_r.shape[0]

#print(no_of_rows)
#2
```